# How Access run a query with all tables stored into a Sharepoint and when not?

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

The question is how works the flow process looking to CPU & network usage in these situations:

**Running a query that contains Just SharepointLists**

All sql request is processed into Sharepoint Server?

**Running a query that contains SharepointLists and local Tables**

In this case, all sharepoint list is downloaded and processed locally?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, access linked tables to SharePoint ALWAYS use a local copy of the data in question.

You can check the “clear” cache on exit, but for performance reasons I don’t suggest you do this.

So what access does, is “first” does a “sync” with the local copy of data (keep in mind in this context I am NOT talking about local access tables – but linked tables ONLY in this context).

What this means is that the sql query is in fact processed local and ONLY a check for updates and to “sync” the local table occurs.

Before Access 2010 (and SharePoint 2010), then this “local” cache was raw xml, and it was VERY slow.

Now, the local database engine is used for such SQL. However, high speed local indexing ONLY works for the PK column – the other columns are (sadly) not indexed. However, because local processing and ram performance is “stupid” fast, then this works rather nice for tables up to 50,000 records.

If you do a join between that linked + “cached” table and a local Access table? Well, if you join on the PK column of the linked table, then this processing occurs “local”. However, if you join on anything but the PK, then you don’t have indexing – this will chew up CPU and ram local – such queries don’t perform that well.

So as a general rule, any SQL you use to “hit” a linked table is in fact “run” local against the local cached table. If that local linked table does NOT have a full cache of data, then a request is made to SharePoint. The pull of data in this case can and will be restricted to your filter, but SharePoint data is xml lists of data – not a table of rows and columns like SQL server. SharePoint does a “decent” job of handling such quires, but do keep in mind that the SQL is not processed server side (it is converted into camel syntax, and this is a “web service” pull, not an ODBC or true database kind of pull).

And yes, the data is downloaded and processed local. However, as noted, Access “retains” this cache of data local. So in theory you can query a 20,000 row table, and VERY little if any network traffic to SharePoint will occur (only a test/check to sync the table). If no table changes occur, then such a query occurs “mostly” local against the local table cache.

Keep in mind this means that such a query can run rather fast, but updates to large tables will still run slow as a turtle, because for each row update local, then a “sync” of that data to SharePoint has to occur. And you can’t run/use server side updates like you can with say SQL server. The reason here is simple, since if you attempt to run an update server side, then a sync of each row will occur down to the client – and you STILL then have a huge network penalty.

So in some cases, such SQL quires against SharePoint will run absolute circles around SQL server. (Because the local table cache can be used). And because the communication from Access to SharePoint is a “web service”, then the technology stack is written around the concept of the web that allows “often” small breaks in the connection. In fact, if your connection is 100% lost, Access will continue to operate on the local data until such time you re-establish an internet connection, and the “sync” of local table data can occur to SharePoint. So this setup allows a “off line” mode – Access can function with a broken connection.

If you use ODBC to SQL server, then “any” small break in the internet connection will break the connection, and you usually have to exit + re-start Access. So from an “internet” point of view, the technology stack used with SharePoint is FAR better choice than SQL server.

However, the big issue is SharePoint lists do NOT scale well for applications with lots of rows, or applications with lots of row updates.

Also keep in mind that all relationships between tables on SharePoint must have a pk ID (number), and the FK must also be a number. So cascade update and cascade delete between SharePoint tables is supported, and it also supported by Access.

So as a general rule, I would limit table sizes to say 10,000 rows, maybe 15,000 tops. And keep in mind that if you using office 365, then query datasets are limited to 5000 rows. If you are running on-site SharePoint, then all of these “throttles” and limits can be turned off.

So applications that update lots of rows in one shot don’t work well with Access to SharePoint. And applications with lots of rows, and lots of relational joins also don’t scale well. Keep in mind there is two types of scaling I speak of here. In this case we talking about large row counts as opposed to “horizontal” scaling with lots of users. SharePoint (and Access) can handle rather large user counts, but large data row counts is a different matter and story.

So really, no sql is processed server side because SharePoint don’t update rows with the SQL engine – it is a web service based update system.

It really comes down to how large the row sets will be. For applications that expect below 10,000 rows, you should be just fine. If you expect larger row counts, then I suggest you use SQL server for the back end, or even SQL Azure if you want a cloud based solution.

edit:
Also, to get acceptable performance, you need Access 2010 or later, and also sharePoint 2010 or later. You need to ensure you check this option for the local cache to work:
[image]